# How to use IPython magic within a script to auto reload modules?

Tags: python, ipython, python-module

I am trying to include some of the IPython built-in magic functions to auto reload modules when I am running a script. So I have tried this:

```
if __IPYTHON__:
    %load_ext autoreload
    %autoreload 2
```

But IPython returns:

```
%load_ext autoreload
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: After `%load_ext autoreload` can you tab-complete `%autoreload`?

Comment: Another try could be to edit your ipython_config.py with `c.InteractiveShellApp.extensions = ['autoreload']` and `c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = ['%autoreload 2']`. This could not help, but it's worth a try.

Comment: @colidyre What do you mean by tab-complete?. Also I don't want to change the ipython_config.py because I want to implement this only on certain scripts, not all of them.

Comment: Tab completion is just e.g. to exclude non printable characters accidentally put in your console or to exclude import errors. You just type `%` and then press tabulator key. Then you should see (there is a chance that you don't have this feature) a list of possible commands. This is very basic and also very fast to check. You can also provide some version information (python and iPython).

Comment: @colidyre, I thought you were referring to something different. I know for sure both lines are fine because I can execute them directly in iPython, but when I include them on the script and run them from there, I get that error. It seems a problem with trying to use magic functions from a script.

Comment: Ok. You've written _when I am working interactively_. This is misleading. I recommend to correct that in your question to clarify this behaviour happens in execution of a script.

Comment: Ok, I edited the text. Hope it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thank you for the link Gall!!! Whit your help I came up with the following solution:

```
from IPython import get_ipython
ipython = get_ipython()

if '__IPYTHON__' in globals():
    ipython.magic('load_ext autoreload')
    ipython.magic('autoreload 2')
```

Comment: Thanks for this! You could even put the first two lines of code inside the if statement for better encapsulation.

Comment: ipython.`magic` is now deprecated, use `run_line_magic` instead